# Red and black balls (Pretty easy I think)

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I was solving a probability exercise, there is 2 jars $U_1$ and $U_2$ each containing $10$ balls.

In $U_1$ there is $6$ red balls and $4$ black balls.
In $U_2$ there is $5$ red balls and $5$ black balls.

A player rolls a fair dice of 6 facing, if he get the numbers 1 or 2, he chooses 2 balls simultaneously from jar $U_1$, if he gets 3,4,5, or 6 he chooses 2 balls from jar $U_2$ randomly and with replacement.

Consider the following events:

$U_1:$The chosen balls are from jar $U_1$

$R:$ The chosen balls are red

A part of the question is to calculate $P(R \cap U_1)$ (i.e. the probability that the chosen balls are red and from jar $U_1$). I worked out the answer using the rule $$P(R\cap U_1)=P(R/U_1)×P(U_1)=\frac{1}{9}$$

But I was thinking about another way to calculate it without using this rule, I thought about $$P(R\cap U_1)=\frac{\frac{1}{3}C_6^2}{\frac{1}{3}C_{10}^2+\frac{2}{3}×10^2}$$

Because we want 2 red balls from jar $U_1$ and that is $\frac{1}{3}C_6^2$ divided by the total number of ways that we can choose 2 balls from $U_1$ or $U_2$ and that is $\frac{1}{3}C_{10}^2$ (for $U_1$) and $\frac{2}{3}×10^2$ (for $U_2$).

But it seems to be wrong, as this gave a different answer than the first one, and ofcourse the first answer is right, but I can't see what I missed? And how can this be solved without using the first mentioned rule?

Thank you for you help...

Comment: Can you clarify what $R$ is?  You say "the probability that **the** chosen ball (*singular*) is red" but there are two balls that were chosen, not one... so "the" is ambiguous here.  Do you mean "both" balls are red, i.e. "the probability that the chosen ball**s are both** red?"  "At least one" ball is red, i.e. "the probability that **a** chosen ball is red?"  Something else?

Comment: @JMoravitz Based on the second part of the question, I think he/she actually means ‘the probability that *both* balls are red’... but I’m not sure.

Comment: @Rainlovingperson given the attempt, that seems logical considering the $\binom{6}{2}$ term appearing there.  Assuming that were the case then the initial attempt giving $\frac{1}{9}$ is the correct attempt, but it should still be clarified by the OP.  @ Fareed, you need to remember that probability being calculated as "number of favorable outcomes" divided by "total number of outcomes" **only** works when those outcomes are equally likely to occur.  There are two possibilities when playing the lottery, you either win or your lose, but the probability of winning is not $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Yes sorry guys I meant the 2 chosen **balls** are red, I'll edit

Comment: @JMoravitz do you mean that if the probability of choosing the balls from $U_1$ was equal to the probability of choosing the balls from $U_2$ it would have worked? Or also the "choosing" must be same (I mean in both the order important or in both not ...)  for it to work?

Comment: Consider a smaller incredibly trivial example... you have two buckets, in the first bucket you have one red ball and nothing else.  In the second bucket you have a billion black balls and nothing else.  You flip a fair coin.  If heads, you grab a ball from the first bucket.  If tails you grab a ball from the second bucket.  It should be *painfully obvious* that there is a 50% chance of drawing a red ball but your attempt would have you think it were $\frac{1}{1000000001}$.

Comment: In order to use $Pr(A)=\frac{|A|}{|\Omega|}$ where $\Omega$ is the sample space, i.e. probability is the number of favorable outcomes divided by the total number of outcomes, then you must have each individual atomic event, i.e. an outcome, must be equally likely to occur.  In this example with the billion black balls, the atomic events describing each different black ball being taken may be equiprobable to eachother but *not* to the atomic event describing taking the red ball which is *far* more likely to occur.  Although not as extreme, the same thing happens in your original example.